# Create a text file and write address of the char array in it

Tags: c, file

I am trying to write address of array buffer in address.txt file.
I do not know why the following code does not work. The following is the code I have:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int func(char *str)
{
   int variable_a;
   char buffer[12];
   
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen( "address.txt, "w");
  fprintf(fp, &buffer);
  fclose(fp);
  


  strcpy(buffer, str);
  
  return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *buf = "hello\n";
  
  if(argc > 1){
    buf = argv[1];
  }

  func(buf);
  printf("Returned Properly\n");
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: `fprintf` takes format string, just like `printf`.

Comment: How can I write buffer address in text file?

Comment: First, you need to write values into `buffer`. It is unintialised, so what happens when you use it is undefined. But if you really want to see the *address* of `buffer`, in a text file, use the format specifier `"%p"`.

Comment: Hint: `fwrite()`. You're not writing the buffer *address*, addresses are useless outside of that particular process, but you must pass a pointer to the buffer *data*.

Comment: `fprintf(fp, "%p", &buffer)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write an address, use `%p` to format to pointer address

```
fprintf(fp, "%p", &buffer);
```

Will do the trick